# PHP: How to remove duplicate arguments in a url?

Tags: php, url, arguments, opencart

I'm trying to write a product filter extension for opencart.

I assign size, color etc. options to the url like this:

> index.php?route=product/category&path=59_63&size=57&color=black

The problem is when I click another color on the page the link goes like this:

> index.php?route=product/category&path=59_63&size=57&color=black&color=brown

As you can see there are duplicated color arguments and it messes up the category listing.
How can I remove same arguments if there is?

The original opencart's link builder function:

```
public function link($route, $args = '', $connection = 'NONSSL') {
    if ($connection ==  'NONSSL') {
        $url = $this->url;  
    } else {
        $url = $this->ssl;  
    }

    $url .= 'index.php?route=' . $route;

    if ($args) {
        $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&')); 
    }

    return $this->rewrite($url);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough information to provide a correct answer, but I'll take a guess.

The problem seems to be with `$args`. It seems that you are taking `$args` from the URL and append to it your new color parameter.

If URL is `index.php?route=product/category&path=59_63&size=57&color=black`, then `$args` is `path=59_63&size=57&color=black`

You append to it `color=brown` and `$args becomes path=59_63&size=57&color=black&color=brown`.

If this is the case, you can do something like this:

```
parse_str($args,$url_params);
$url_params['color'] = 'brown'; //-- overwrites color=black with color=brown
$args = http_build_query($url_params);
```

Then pass $args to your `link()` function.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to remove duplicate parameters.
uou have not to add it.

use `http_build_query()` to create a query string

Comment: I couldn't understand what should I do and I have added the original opencart's link builder function to the main message...

Answer (score 0):

This is really nothing to do with opencart's link builder, it's done outside of that so as not to make any core changes. You need to set the value when you use $this->url->link in your controller code for your category. When you are getting all of the colors that you will use for filters, be sure to unset the color attribute passed into the second parameter of the link